# lognormal distribution radius to volume

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

How do I prove (and find the new parameters) that if the radius R of a sphere is lognormally distributed, its volume is also lognormally distributed?

All I can think of is: $F_V(x) = F(\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3 \leq x) = F_R(\sqrt[3]{\frac{3x}{4 \pi}}) $

so $f_R(\sqrt[3]{\frac{3x}{4 \pi}}) = \frac{1}{z \sqrt{2 \pi \sigma ^2}} exp(-\frac{lnz - \mu}{2 \sigma ^2})   $ where $z = \sqrt[3]{\frac{3x}{4 \pi}} $ but then I don't know to to separate the coefficients to figure out new $\mu'$ and $\sigma' ^2$
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that if $R$ is lognormally distributed with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$, then $R = e^X$, where $X$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.

Therefore, for any nonzero real scalar $k$, the variable $R^k = e^{kX}$ is also lognormal because $kX$ is normal with mean $k \mu$ and standard deviation $k \sigma$.

In other words, because scale transformations of a normally distributed random variable are also normally distributed, and because lognormal random variables are exponential transformations of normal random variables, then nonzero *powers* of lognormal random variables are lognormal.

Similarly, location transformations of a normally distributed random variable are also normally distributed, so multiplication of a lognormal random variable by a *positive constant* also results in a lognormal random variable.  That is to say,

$$c R^k = c e^{kX} = e^{k X + \log c},$$ so the new parameters are $k \mu + \log c$ and $k \sigma$.  In your case, $k = 3$ and $c = \frac{4}{3}\pi$.

Comment: Thank you! Does the $\frac{4}{3} \pi $ change anything?

Comment: @sucksatmath Yes.  Please see my edited answer.